# Django: How to use Django's view functions instead of a hardcoded action?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

A want to avoid hardcoding my form actions in the Django templates. Instead of 
`action="/en/accounts/change_profile/"` I would prefer something like `action=views.change_profile`.

Is there way to connect a view function to a form action without necessarily using a String?

**My form**

```
<form action="/en/accounts/change_profile/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**My view**

```
@login_required
def change_profile(request):
    form = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.UserProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():  
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/en/accounts/profile')

else:
    form = forms.UserProfileForm()

return shortcuts.render(request, 'project/change_profile.html',
                        {'form':form,})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^en/accounts/change_profile/', 'app.views.change_profile', name='change_profile'),
```

now in your template:

```
{% url change_profile %}
```

Comment: this works in django <= 1.4; in 1.5 @AntonBessov answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [url-Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) like:

```
<form action="{% url 'change_profile' %}" method="post">
```

after you define routing. [Here you have some examples.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#examples)

There is a little bit trickie part with locale. As I remember 2009, you can handle it by middleware. But now its easier: [Language prefix in urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns), like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(_(r'^accounts/change_profile/$'), 'views.change_profile', name='change_profile'),
)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. It should be `{% url 'app.views.change_profile' %}`.

Comment: May be. I don't use Django for many years. But if I look to examples, this should work in named url() ('name'-argument).